# Telerik AJAX spreadsheet how to get the edited sheets in backend (webforms)

Tags: webforms, telerik, spreadsheet

I am using Telerik AJAX spreadsheet to edit excel sheets in the front end. Now I want to save the sheets in database from the backend (.cs file).

I am trying the following line of code:

```
List<Telerik.Web.Spreadsheet.Worksheet> lista = RadSpreadsheet1.Sheets;
```

But unable to populate the edited sheets in the variable lista.